# jQuery AJAX update widget as page loads

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to retrieve the number of devices from my database (by counting rows) and present them in a widget with the updated value as the page loads.

Here's my code:

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="widget-panel widget-style-2 white-bg">
                <i class="ion-eye text-pink"></i> 
                <h2 class="m-0 counter"><span id="server_count">100</span></h2>
                <div>Servers</div>
            </div>
        </div>

...

    $(function (){

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'dashboard/analytics/server_count',
            success: function(result) {
                //alert(result);
                $('#server_count').html(result);
                },
            error: function() {
                alert("problem");
                }

        });

    });
```

The alert shows the correct value in the success function, but I'm having trouble updating the div as the page is rendered; that is, it still shows the default static value (100).

Any ideas on what I'm missing? How should I write this so that the default value always gets overwritten by the dynamic value pulled from the DB, in time for the page load? Thanks!

Comment: what is the response of the ajax request?

Comment: It pulls an integer which corresponds to the number of rows in my table

Comment: if the response of your request is a integer or string number then there's nothing wrong on the ajax request. you can try to check any error's on the developer console if there are any errors

Comment: ok, no errors on the console

Comment: When/how is this function ran? Is there a button to click or does it run when the page is loaded?

Comment: Is the span with id `server_count` in the DOM when you do the ajax call?

Comment: @Karl Galvez: should run on page load

Comment: @ Rickkwa: how do i check if it's in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your function is in `$( document ).ready(function() });` Something like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'dashboard/analytics/server_count',
            success: function(result) {
                //alert(result);
                $('#server_count').html(result);
                },
            error: function() {
                alert("problem");
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ah.. yet, it is, but no change. Curious thing is, if i add alert($('#server_count').html()); to within the success function as the first entry to get the current value, I get "undefined". It doesn't pull the static 100.

Comment: Not sure then. I made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xch1fLsx/ and with the same principles (no ajax) and it works as expected. Maybe posting more code could help pin down your issue?!?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem to be the counter-up plugin, called by the class 'counter' on the h2 selector. Not sure yet why the counting animation prevented the display of the ajax result, but after removing the class, the values get updated as expected.